# Cannot generate doxygen chm/html output from source code

Tags: c++, doxygen, header-files, doxygen-wizard

I am unable to generate chm/html output from Doxygen 1.8.6. I want to generate the method descriptions listed in a cpp file given below. I've included the file in the doxygen config file in the INPUT tag. All I want my output to show the methods in the cpp file. There is also a header file .h with the following:

**API.h**

```
extern "C" 
{
  #include "..\Include\APIDef.h"

  AFX_MIRASTER_API MIRASIO_ReturnCode MIRASIO_ConvertOperation(
    const wchar_t* InputFilePath, const wchar_t* OutputFilePath,
    const wchar_t* DstDriverString, MIRASIO_CompressionType CompressionType,
    unsigned int CompressionLevel, bool MaintainOverview,
    unsigned int srcField, unsigned int srcEvent,unsigned int srcBand,
    unsigned int nProgressTrackerHandle = InvalidTracker);
```

**API.cpp**

```
/**
 * 
 * @brief Convert operation (Old). Converts a specified file to MRR format.
 * 
 *
 * \param[in]       InputFilePath           Full path to the input file.
 * \param[in]       OutputFilePath          Full path to the output file.
 * \param[in]       DstDriverString         Driver to use to create the output file.
 * \param[in]       CompressionType         Type of compression.
 * \param[in]       CompressionLevel        Level of the compression.
 * \param[in]       MaintainOverview        True to maintain overview.
 * \param[in]       srcField                Source field index to resample (when source file is of MRR raster type).
 * \param[in]       srcEvent                Source event type.
 * \param[in]       srcBand                 Band of the source file.
 * \param[in]       nProgressTrackerHandle  Progress tracker handle.
 *
 * @return <code>MIRASIO_ReturnCode</code>.
 */

MIRASIO_ReturnCode MIRASIO_ConvertOperation (
  const wchar_t* InputFilePath, const wchar_t* OutputFilePath,
  const wchar_t* DstDriverString, MIRASIO_CompressionType CompressionType,
  unsigned int CompressionLevel, bool MaintainOverview, unsigned int srcField,
  unsigned int srcEvent, unsigned int srcBand, unsigned int nProgressTrackerHandle)
{   
  return RasterOperationsContainer::AcquireProcessingOperation()->ConvertOperation(
           InputFilePath,OutputFilePath, DstDriverString,CompressionType,
           CompressionLevel, MaintainOverview, srcField, srcEvent, srcBand,
           nProgressTrackerHandle);
}
```

How do I generate the doc for the methods listed in the cpp file? What parameters I need to change in the doxygen config file?

Answer (score 0):

Check these parameters:

```
INPUT = api.h API.cpp

# To generate HTML output
GENERATE_HTML = YES
# Where HTML docs will be put
HTML_OUTPUT = html

# If set to YES doxygen generates three additional HTML index files:
# index.hhp, index.hhc, and index.hhk
# The index.hhp is a project file that can be read by Microsoft's HTML Help
# Workshop. The HTML Help Workshop contains a compiler that can convert all
# HTML output generated by doxygen into a single compiled HTML file (.chm)
GENERATE_HTMLHELP = YES
```